# How to get scroll height of multine textField (office ui fabric react)

Tags: reactjs, textfield, multiline, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to get the scroll height of the multi-line text field. I have used office UI fabric react `TextField`.

I have tried to get the `TextField` scroll height in the `ComponentDidUpdate()` /jQuery, but it always returns `scrollHeight` as 0.

`AutoHeightAdjust` property works fine when I am entering input in the `TextField`. But, when I am trying to show the data from the state in the `TextField` it does not fit to the size of the content. That's where the real problem is.

This is my tag:

```
<TextField disabled={this.isDisabled} autoAdjustHeight value={this.state.Action} onChanged={this.handleAction} multiline resizable={true} rows={6}/>
```

Comment: Can you share a working example?

Comment: <TextField multiline value={this.state.Actions} resizable={true} rows={6} autoAdjustHeight={true}  />

Comment: A codepen of some sort with your scenario would be much more helpful. https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/OKRRLR here is starting one.